# Databricks widgets

Tags: python, widget, databricks

My question is about widgets to pass parameters in databricks. I am using widgets in one notebook to set parameters. Then, I am running this initial notebook from other notebooks. I want the chosen parameters to be pulled in. 
For example, in Notebook 1 I have:
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("start_year", "2011", [str(x) for x in range(2008, 2021)], "Earliest year")
start_year=dbutils.widgets.get("start_year")
print("The start_year is " + dbutils.widgets.get("start_year"))

The print statement correctly prints whatever year the user has selected.

In Notebook 2, which runs Notebook 1 using %run, it will only print the default year, in this case 2011, no matter what is selected. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[From the widget docs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/widgets.html) (all the way at the bottom):

> If you run a notebook that contains widgets, the specified notebook is run with the widget’s default values. You can also pass in values to widgets. For example:
>   `%run /path/to/notebook $X="10" $Y="1"`

**Have you considered setting "notebook 1" to store the value, at least temporarily, in dbfs rather than in a variable? Then you can retrieve whatever was set in "notebook 1".**

i.e. Assuming the user must visit and set the parameter in Notebook 1

**Notebook 1**

```
start_year=dbutils.widgets.get("start_year") 
myTmpTxt = "The start_year is " + dbutils.widgets.get("start_year")
print(myTmpTxt)
with open('/dbfs/mnt/tmp/tmpStoreYear.txt', 'w') as savedYear:
  savedYear.write(myTmpTxt)
```

**Notebook 2**

```
openQuery = open('/dbfs/mnt/tmp/tmpStoreYear.txt', 'rb')
openQuery.read()
```

Also, there is an option specify widget parameters using  `dbutils.notebook.run` ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html))
However, it still runs as a separate job, and the values won't be imported to your "notebook 2"

Hope this helps!